# Questions that don't provide real code

Tags: discussion, questions

Occasionally I see questions in which the asker provides "pseudo code" that is supposed to represent their problem but sometimes doesn't because its reduced form is too different from the original code base. While it is commendable that the OP is trying to avoid clutter (and code dumps) and reduce their problem to a minimalistic example, it can be annoying because it turns into a guessing game and egging the asker to edit their question until it reaches an answerable state. In particular, I can only think of two questions in recent memory:

[Different classes that might be passed to constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415935/different-classes-that-might-be-passed-to-constructor)

[c++ float subtraction rounding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434292/c-float-subtraction-rounding-error)

The first question, the OP originally posted no code. Then his edit contained an insignificant typo (indicating that it wasn't his real code.) Luckily the answerer was able to figure it out although the question as it stands I think is too vague. There are different approaches that may satisfy OP but just looking at the question you cannot formulate a specific answer.

The second question also doesn't contain real code (as admitted from the OP) and so it is impossible to reproduce his results and formulate a specific answer. While the commenters correctly directed the OP to floating point resources, the question as it stands still is not in an answerable state other than "go read how floating point numbers work" which makes it a duplicate.

What is the best way to handle this situation to minimize back and forth with OP?

Comment: Code extracts are always a problem because one of the main causes of debug failure is looking in the wrong place. My preference is to ask for a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org). A complete program that reproduces the problem must contain the key code.

Comment: If a reproducible example is necessary and it is not provided (or it does not correctly represent the problem), the question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle the issue is to state to the OP that the provided pseudocode doesn't accurately return the error asked about, and can they please post the relevant piece of the actual code.  I've never had anyone tell me "No", when they know I'm trying to help.

Comment: I disagree. The best way to handle the question is to leave a comment to the poster that the code posted is invalid, that we can't debug or resolve issues with fake, invalid code, tell them they need to provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and vote to close as off-topic because we can't debug code that isn't actually submitted.

Comment: So the best option is to say, "You suck, now go away"?  I can't say I can subscribe to a website that endorses that mentality.  You can catch more flies with honey, you know.

Comment: No, the best option is to say "You've not provided sufficient information. If you'd like us to help, please provide it.". There's a difference between asking for quality questions and being rude. If the poster can't be bothered to provide the details properly, we don't need the question here. We're not trying to catch flies; we're trying to build a knowledge base, and you can't do that with crap. There are lots of sites where you can post manure; we don't want SO to be among them.

Comment: You've contradicted yourself.  How is this second answer any different from what my answer was?

Comment: I haven't contradicted anything. The proper response is precisely what I said in my first comment. If the poster can't/won't improve the question, then yes, they should go away. Leave a comment telling them they need to improve the question and vote to close it. Once they've done so, it automatically gets moved into the reopen queue. I said it the first time, I said it the second time, and I've now said it again. I'm not sure what part isn't clear. Vote to close poor questions, with a comment as to why if you care to do so (I usually do). Your suggestion is to leave them and plead for details.

Comment: Where do people get the mentality that closing is rude? It isn't.