# Asking questions when I am limited as to what I can share

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I haven't posted a question in a while which has gotten a downvote, but I sure do make it hard for people to help me. This is because I am highly restricted on what I can post to get help on by my employment contract. So usually I cannot post actual application code.

What makes it worse is that when I sanitize my code for pushing to plunker, I end up not being able to replicate the issue. So sanitizing the code hides the problem. My latest one is on an SPA that is a dozen controllers, popups, and and more.

I have ended up answering my own issues in the past, and sometimes it is even helpful for others.

Should I bother posting the question, if I know I cannot share the full code, and maybe just post after I figure it out? Or should I continue, just in case there is a lucky soul who has ran into this with fix?

I fall into into the category of this question too often: [Questions that don't provide real code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269476/questions-that-dont-provide-real-code).

Other suggestions welcomed, too.

Comment: Thank you @JoshCaswell. I added the mentoring tag before realizing what it really was. I have since learned.

Comment: No problemo; that's why we can all edit each other's stuff.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "I have ended up answering my own issues in the past..." <- why it's difficult for people doing it right to have a question to ask once you've completed the [check list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Two acronyms for you: MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. (Copied from an answer below.) "...there are plenty of times that sanitizing has only hidden the problem, rather than exposing it..." Bottom line. I don't work on easy projects, I work on project that other programmers fail on. I understand MCVE, being the person who added the alternate definition to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCVE. Thought, I won't say that I'm not a bit sloppy. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should *never* share the full code. You should post a [test case](http://sscce.org): a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your problem. It is contrived and abstracts away sensitive details of your organisation. It is an absolute *must* that you develop the skill of developing testcases.

Questions on Stack Overflow that ask "why doesn't this code work?" *require* a testcase, so your concern regarding posting "real-life" code is moot.

When you killed the bug by "sanitising" your code, you just got one step closer to solving it. This is not part of posting to the internet for help: this is part of *debugging*. Keep sanitising and unsanitising until you've got it!

Comment: I can accept '"why doesn't this code work?" require a testcase'. That is a reasonable expectation. Glad I asked.

Comment: @Brian: Glad to help

Comment: This is sort of dual to [How much do you want to know?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266583/1281433) (where I answered, "I want to know everything about the problem. I don't want to know anything about anything that's not the problem").

Comment: Why is the last ¶aragraph struck out?  I think it makes a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Because there are plenty of times that sanitizing has only hidden the problem, rather than exposing it. I still have no idea of why my drop down controls were crashing all browsers, when doing any of the  ngBind. And the browser crashes actually made solving the problem dang near impossible. When I sanitized the code, and added back to the point of crash, I was back to the exact point of where I was when I first had the crash.

Answer (score 10):

Do not post code that does not reproduce your problem. If sanitizing the code fixes the problem, this really indicates that you have already discovered where the problem lies and don't need help. Do not post questions about code problems without a reproducing case.

Comment: Actually sanitizing usually hides the issue, not solve it. Like my crashing all browsers when I was using ng binding on dropboxes.

Comment: @Brian, I strongly disagree that sanitizing *usually* hides the problem.  In your repeated comments, it's clear it happened to you.  But I think you are overgeneralizing.  In my experience, if I change the code such that I can no longer repro, I've *usually* discovered a clue.

Comment: @KirkWoll I won't say that EVERY time I sanitize it hides the problem, but my specific example of crashing all browsers, it did. Fortunately the people at MS followed up with me for a suggestion of not using dropdown box , but use the dropdown button in TBS. For them it was a case that they had the details of the crash dump file. My apologies if I made it sound like every time.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure we don't have to tell you that reducing a problem to a SSCE is helpful. It's helpful to you long before it's helpful to us. Reality is, of course, it's not always possible.

In descending order of goodness, I'd list:

1. An SSCE
2. A coherent description of an issue, including some description of what sorts of SSCE failed to reproduce it.
3. A giant dump of code.

I can nearly guarantee downvotes for case 3. Frankly, #2 is still not so hot. You're really going to have to impress people that you, yourself, are an expert, that there's a really good reason why an SSCE hasn't worked, and that you've instrumented the heck out of the situation to sneak up, maximally, on the nature of the issue.

Now, chances are, if you're chasing this process, you will find the solution before you find a concise question to post here. That's the nature of stackoverflow.com; it's not a place to recruit brainstorming on a hard problem.

Answer (score 4):

> *when I sanitize my code for pushing to plunker, I end up not being able to replicate the issue. So sanitizing the code hides the problem.*

That is usually my problem solver. When you are trying to make a question, you usually go around stuff you haven't noticed yet.

That happens not only when grabbing code snipets, but also  when explaining the context so others can understand.

You are never obligated to share things that you can't. You will always need to create your own test scenarios. Only things that could not be able to be shared are, probably ideas or purposes of your code, and that should be easily to hide.

Answer (score 0):

If sanitizing hides the issue but doesn't solve it, then your sanitized example is fine. Either way, you can always post it and then explain what happens in your production version and ask why that might be - likely the sanitized code is sufficient to make it obvious.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thx.